# Xamarin.Forms Prism Master in MasterDetailPage could not be loaded from separate XAML file

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

i tried to move a the master in MasterDetailPage into separate file. As soon as i do this, the MD Page is not longer loaded.

MasterDetailPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                  prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismMasterDetailSample.Views;assembly=PrismMasterDetailSample"
                  x:Class="PrismMasterDetailSample.Views.PMasterDetailPage">


  <MasterDetailPage.Master Title="Menu">
    <!--<local:MenuPage />   <========== does not work -->
    <ContentPage Title="Default">
      <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="About" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="MyNavigationPage/ViewA?id=A" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>


  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:PTabbedPage />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

Codebehind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PrismMasterDetailSample.Views
{
    public partial class PMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public PMasterDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the MenuPage XAML

```
"1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="PrismMasterDetailSample.Views.MenuPage"
             Title="Menu">


  <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="20">
    <Button Text="DetailPage1" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" HorizontalOptions ="LayoutOptions.Center"/>

  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The Code behind:
    using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace PrismMasterDetailSample.Views
{
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PrismMasterDetailSample.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public DelegateCommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }
        private INavigationService _navigationService;

        public MenuPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Navigate);
        }

        private void Navigate()
        {

                _navigationService.NavigateAsync("DetailPage1");

        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure that is a trivial issue, but i didn't get the point.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the answer ;-D

Add "Title" to the MenuPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="PrismMasterDetailSample.Views.MenuPage"
             Title="Menu">


  <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="20">
    <Button Text="DetailPage1" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" HorizontalOptions ="LayoutOptions.Center"/>

  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```